invalid conversion from 'const T*' to 'T*' using type aliases
I'm using the type aliases for pointer and const pointer and I don't understand why there is difference between returning a const pointer and a const_pointer.
I assumed that const pointer, in this case, is equivalent to const int*, but I'm getting an invalid conversion compile error:

error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'S::pointer {aka int*}

struct S
{
  using pointer = int*;
  using const_pointer = const int*;

  // const_pointer get() const { return &i; }    // OK
  const pointer get() const { return &i; } // ERROR

  int i = {};
};
    
int main()
{
  const S s;
  s.get();
}


const int* is a mutable pointer to a const int.  Your const pointer is a const pointer to a mutable int.

It's the difference between const (int*) and (const int)*.

I prefer the Clang error messages: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'const pointer' (aka 'int *const') with an rvalue of type 'const int *'. const pointer and pointer const is the same.

The difference is in what is const. In const_pointer the integer is const, in const pointer the pointer is const.

All of your const confusion will go away if you consistently put const on the right.  pointer const and int* const mean the same thing, and are obviously different from const_pointer (AKA int const*).

@MilesBudnek I think part of the confusion here is the common beginner one in not realising that the pointer and what it points at are two different things.

@john That may be true, but even for people with a bit more C++ experience, the fact that const pointer isn't the same as what you would get with a simple textual expansion of the alias (that is, const int*) is counterintuitive.

As the wise ancients say: "leading const is misleading".

I find it helps if you stop putting const on the left.  If I rephrase your question:
struct S
{
  using pointer = int*;
  using const_pointer = int const*;
  using pointer_const = int*const;

  // const_pointer get() const { return &i; }    // OK
  // pointer_const get() const { return &i; }    // ERROR
  pointer const get() const { return &i; } // ERROR

  int i = {};
};

int main()
{
  const S s;
  s.get();
}

I have replaced const int* with int const*.  As a general rule in C++, const in a type applies to the component of the type on the left.  Only when there is no type on the left does it violate this rule.
When there is no component on the left, it then looks at the local expression of the type - where const is added.  It moves "one step right", and follows the apply on the left rule.  So:
const pointer

becomes
pointer const 

And that becomes
int*const

not
int const*

The second part is understanding that a "pointer to const int" is different than a "const pointer to a non-const int".  In one case, we are pointing at something we cannot modify; in the other, we cannot motifiy which object we are pointing to, but we can modify that object.
Once you stop allowing "const on the left" - once you translate (at least in your head) where const is from being on the left to being on the right of the thing it modifies - a lot of the confusion evaporates.
The last part of confusion is that the transformation from "on the left" to "on the right" cares about the type as described where const is, not the full actual expanded type.

This is exactly why I don't put the const on the left. Types are easy as long as you read right to left and const is in the correct place. int const* => Pointer to Const Int and int*const => Const Pointer to int

@MartinYork East const best, West const worst!
